# How to select all using IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using MVC3, I have a Student Repository (in a project) and a StudentService (in another project). In the service I want to create a function that returns all of the students that are in the db table. This is a new way of doing things for me so I'm a bit new. in the GetAllStudents Function below, How could I change the syntax to select all.

In Repository:

```
      namespace SpeakOut.Data
{
   public class StudentRepository
{
    SpeakOutDataContext context;
    private Table<StudentEntity> table;
    public StudentRepository()
    {
        context = new SpeakOutDataContext();
        table = context.GetTable<StudentEntity>();
    }


    public IQueryable<Student> Select()
    {
        return table.Select(x => new Student
                                {
                                    WNumber = x.WNumber,
                                    CatalogueYear = x.CatalogueYear,
                                    Standing = x.Standing
                                });
    }
}
```

}

In Services:

```
   namespace SpeakOut.Services
   {
  public class StudentService
 {
    private StudentRepository repository;
    public StudentService()
    {
        repository = new StudentRepository(); 

    }

    public IQueryable<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return repository.Select().All(x => x.FirstName) ; //**This line is where I don't know how I would call all the students**
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Oh wait why couldn't I just say return repositry.Select()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<Student> GetAllStudents()
{
    return repository.Select();
}
```

The code above just a pass-through method. The only benefit is hiding the repository behind the service and perhaps by giving it a better name.

At this point no data has been retrieved. The collection of data is deferred until `IQuerable` is being used for example when `.ToList()` is called.  The benefit of leaving it as `IQuerablye` is that additional filters and sort orders can be added by code further down the line. These additions will be used by the LINQ provider.

Comment: haha yea I was thinking to hard on that one..I'm a dummy. Thanks!

Comment: Compiler Error CS1501: No overload for method 'Select' takes '0' arguments

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need just a blank Select, you can just call .AsQueryable, or just return 'table' as an IQueryable.